# Are there Commodore BASIC 7.0 music demos?

Tags: basic, commodore-128, sid

Commodore BASIC 7.0 that came with the Commodore 128 provided commands for playing music notes and setting different instruments. The play function even had a feature that played a note in the background, so that it was possible to play notes simultaneously. While I understand that these features are still quite limited in comparison to machine language IRQ players, I wonder if there exist some non-trivial BASIC V7.0 music demos.

I am aware of music pieces in BASIC using lots of POKEs for the Commodore 64 (for example [these ones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6UYzU-mtwI)) and I know that most of them would run on the C128 as well, but I'm explicitly looking for demos that use BASIC V7.0 commands like PLAY, FILTER and ENVELOPE.

Comment: I programmed a couple of short pieces of music on using C128 BASIC back in the day, but the only advantages it would have over other music software would be the fact that it was built into the C128 without having to be acquired separately, and the fact that it could run while a C128 BASIC program was running.  Other programs like the SidPlayer in "All About the Commodore 64 Volume II" were better for most other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly examples of outstanding music, I knew that there was a C128 demo program written in BASIC to show off the capabilities of BASIC 7.0. In addition to graphics, it also demonstrated some music capabilities. I believe the 8-bit Guy featured it in his [Commodore 128 video on history of Commodore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzMsgnnDIRE), but there is also another one that I found from a quick google search here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyR9aEVNP5Y. If anything, this gives two public examples.

Would love to hear if anyone has found anything more elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

For the records: I just found some C128 BASIC music program using `PLAY` commands in the [Dual Demo by Flexman](https://csdb.dk/release/?id=110215) The music code is at line 7000 and following.